# Changing Mysql Column Names

Tags: php, mysql, alter

I want to change various column names using:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE COLUMN oldname newname datatype(length);
```

This is easy except for the last part: datatype(length). It seems silly to need to specify that since I don't want to change the column type or length, only its name, but from what I've read, specifying that is mandatory. *I need automated code, NOT a  command that merely displays the table from which datatype(length) is displayed on a screen*; I want to put those values into `PHP` variable(s) so they can be manipulated by other `PHP` code. Thus I'd appreciate code that gives me $datatype and $length, if the latter is applicable.

Answer (score 1):

You can select that information from the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) table.

```
select
  DATA_TYPE,
  CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
  IS_NULLABLE,
  NUMERIC_SCALE,
  NUMERIC_PRECISION
  -- And many other properties
from
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where
  TABLE_NAME = 'tablename' and
  COLUMN_NAME = 'yourcolumn'
```

Comment: What is the exact PHP code to use to put that information into $datatype and $length variables?

Comment: It works just as any other query. You can just execute the query and read the results. You can do this using `mysqli`, `PDO`, or any framework you prefer.

Comment: I get this error message:

Could not successfully run query (select DATA_TYPE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = MY_DATA and COLUMN_NAME = 'var100' ) from database: Unknown column 'MY_DATA' in 'where clause'

when I run this code:

//  MY_DATA is a constant for the table name
$query = "select DATA_TYPE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = MY_DATA and COLUMN_NAME = 'var100' ";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$datatype = $row["DATA_TYPE"];
}

echo "Data type is $datatype";

How do I modify that code to correct the error?

Comment: You need to quote the table name as well. `where TABLE_NAME = 'MY_DATA'`.